# Adding button to dynamically generated HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to add a button for each row of the dynamically generated HTML table using JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
// helper function        
function addCell(tr, text) {
    var td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = text;
    return td;
}

// insert data
list.forEach(function (item) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    var button = document.createElement('button'); 
    var bText = document.createTextNode('View'); 
    button.appendChild(bText); 
    addCell(row, item.itemName);
    addCell(row, '$ ' + item.total.toFixed(2));
    addCell(row, button);
});
```

I managed to print out all other fields except the button. The column for the button just simply printed out this:

```
[object HTMLButtonElement]
```

Just wondering if there is anyway to add a image button to the dynamically generated table? Upon selecting the button, I wanted to get the value of the row and pass as parameter to another function as well.

Comment: Can u share fiddle or snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Spz/23/). What you want i dont know. This way you can reach the line.

```
var previousitem=null;
function removeRowbyItem(item) {
      item.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor="red";
      if(previousitem!=null){
         previousitem.style.backgroundColor="";
         console.log(previousitem);
      }
    previousitem=item.parentElement.parentElement;
}
removeRow.innerHTML = "click me";
removeRow.onclick = function() {
  removeRowbyItem(this);
};
```

Comment: Is there anyway to set the background color of selected row?

Comment: Update my answer @hyperfkcb

Comment: Sorry but there is a slight problem because let's say the row is limited to single select. Is there anyway to clear the previous selected row before highlighting the new one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `td.appendChild(button);`

```
function addCell(tr, text) {
    var td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = text;
    return td;
}
//for append button
function addButtonToCell(tr, button) {
    var td = tr.insertCell();
    td.appendChild(button);
    return td;
}
// insert data
list.forEach(function (item) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    var button = document.createElement('button'); 
    var bText = document.createTextNode('View'); 
    button.appendChild(bText); 
    addCell(row, item.itemName);
    addCell(row, '$ ' + item.total.toFixed(2));
    addButtonToCell(row, button);
});
```